# How to handle routing of anchor clicks in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I have a nav bar with below code. but when i click on the anchor element the relative path doesn't get appended to the application url and eventually router not working. How do i make it work?

```
   <nav class="ui menu inverted navbar">
        <a href="\test1" class="brand item">Test1</a>
        <a href="\test2" class="active item">Test2</a>
        <a href="\register" class="item">Register</a>
        <a href="\login" class="item aligned right">Login</a>
    </nav>
```

One option i got is to have a router configured in my app.ts/js and then use the router object to get the menu items like this. as per this [post](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/aurelia/aurelia_routing.htm)

```
 <nav>
      <ul>
         <li repeat.for = "row of router.navigation">
            <a href.bind = "row.href">${row.title}</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
```

and the other way is to use click.delegate on each anchor element and in the model  return `this.router.navigate("specific path like \login or \register")` from the on Click function

Comment: I'm having the same issue. The browser interprets all hrefs with "#myID" as absolute, rather than navigating within the same page. Did you ever figure this out? I'm using pushstate.

Answer (score 0):

For random usage of anchor tags that you want to use routes from the aurelia router, you can use the following format:

```
<a route-href="route:route-as-declared-in-router">Click Me!</a>
```